# Why do the horses on this vase have too many legs?

Tags: ancient-greece, sports

Why do the horses have too many legs? They appear to have an extra set, why is this?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is a depiction of "my two horses are as fast as your four horses".

Comment: Comments are for clarification from the author of the question/answer; not to make fun of them....

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The number of legs is correct. It's the number of heads that is wrong.

The chariot depicted is an [Olympic quadriga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadriga) which was driven by four horses.

The artist probably found it difficult to make a design that included all four horse heads, so he just drew two of them.

Comment: WoW! So, wonderful. Having problem? Remove two heads!! But still have to draw the legs!!

Comment: Or they are pairwise perfectly in sync, so two of the heads are hidden

Comment: How about tails?

Comment: I love how the reasoning is basically "because he was lazy".

Comment: The numberof torsoes is also wrong...

Comment: This was the last vase of the run of 400 they were making for the olympics - hoping they'd be hot sellers. They were tired, in a rush, and knew the customers wouldn't notice until after the games.

Comment: Here is a very similar picture but with 4 tails. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariot_racing#/media/File:Chariot_race_Met_L.1999.10.12.jpg Apparently this was a mass produced item, and in one case the artist was just lazy to add the correct number of tails.

Comment: Here is one more: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Chariots_in_ancient_Greek_art#/media/File:Chariot_terma_Staatliche_Antikensammlungen_1452.jpg almost identical but with 4 tails.

Comment: And more: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Chariots_in_ancient_Greek_art#/media/File:Museo_archeologico_di_Firenze,_Vaso_Fan%C3%A7ois_5.JPG

Comment: HNQ HA! This is why I love this site!

Comment: @vsz They don't even need to be pairwise perfectly in sync; the other two horses could just be eclipsed by the two horses in front, thereby eclipsed. Seems like a likely scenario (or perhaps more likely, an excuse) for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 7):

I think Tyler is right, but it's also possible that the horses were depicted running as fast as Marvin here.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cartoonbucket.com](http://www.cartoonbucket.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Marvin-Running-Fast-tbr5417.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I wonder what archeologists will say about that picture in the year 3016. "Gosh, in 2016, they were still too dumb to properly count feet..."